# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de comparar el valor de un nibble en C#?

Tags: c#, optimización

Tengo un byte, cuando el byte termina en `2` en hexadecimal, ósea que su segundo nibble es un 2, tengo que hacer ciertas acciones.

Ejemplos:

- Caso **`false`**: `byte myByte = 99; //63 en hexadecimal`
- Caso **`false`**: `byte myByte = 49; //31 en hexadecimal`
- Caso **`true`**:  `byte myByte = 18; //12 en hexadecimal`
- Caso **`true`**:  `byte myByte = 34; //22 en hexadecimal`

Mi solución es la siguiente, no me convence del todo por qué es un tanto rudimentaria.

```
var nibble = Convert.ToString(myByte, 16).PadLeft(2,'0').ToCharArray()[1];
if(nibble == '2')
//aqui va mi codigo
```

Utilice algunos operadores de [bitwise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sbf85k1c.aspx), pero creo que no supe usarlos correctamente por qué no obtuve el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los operadores bitwise son tus amigos en este caso.

En este particular caso, el operador `&` o `Bitwise And` de C# es el que necesitas.

Suponiendo que necesitas saber cual es el valor del segundo nibble, puedes hacer la siguiente comparación:

```
byte theByte = ObtenerByteDeAlgunLado();
if ((theByte & 0x0F) == 0x02) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Si, es 0x02, cambio y fuera.\n"); // Hacer lo que sea :)
}
```

En dado caso, puedes cambiar el valor, en vez de `0x0F` puedes ver si el bit con valor `2` está activo, por ejemplo:

```
byte elByte = 0xF6; // 1111 0110 en binario.
if ((elByte & 0x02) == 0x02) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("El byte 0x02 está activo.\n");
}
```

Si necesitas entender como funcionan los operadores bit a bit, acá abajo te dejo un ejemplo de las diversas operaciones:

- `&`: deja encendidos los bits que concuerden entre ambos operandos
- `|`: deja encendido un bit de cualquiera de los operandos
- `^`: deja encendido o uno u otro de los bits de los operandos.

```
    1: 0 0 0 0  | 0 0 1 1    // Binario
    2: 0 0 1 0  | 0 1 0 1
    +-----------+-------+
    &: 0 0 0 0  | 0 0 0 1    // Resultado de bitwise &
    |: 0 0 1 0  | 0 1 1 1
    ^: 0 0 1 0  | 0 1 1 0
```

A modo de recomendación, si vas a trabajar con operadores bit a bit, utiliza valores hexadecimales en tus asignaciones, por ejemplo:

```
int deadbeef = 0xDEADBEEF;
```

De esta forma se vuelve mas legible al trabajar.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias!, lo habia intentado como la segunda opcion `if ((elByte & 0x02) == 0x02)` pero no me daba los resultados esperados. Por otro lado, pudieras explicarme por se usa `0x0F`?

Comment: Utilicé `0x0F` porque en binario es 0000 1111, y como puedes ver, el bit con valor de 2 está encendido, así si el valor del bit es el esperado, entonces la condicion es verdadera.

Comment: Ya lo comprendo, soy nuevo usando los bitwise. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te ha funcionado, recuerda marcar la respuesta :)

Comment: Si ya le di click, pero necesito reputacion de 15 para que se marque.