# ¿Qué significa el operador | en la declaración y asignacion de un entero en Java?

Tags: java

¿Qué significa el operador `|` en la declaración de un `int`?

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Main{
  public static void main (String... args){
        int c = 20|30|1000;
        int d = 20|30|20;
        int e = 1000|20|1;
        System.out.println(c+" "+d+" "+e);
  }
}
```

Genera:

> ```
> 1022 30 1021
> ```

Comment: Relacionado: [Link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/56123/4499)

Comment: Esto es parte de la sintaxis bàsica de Java, y de una larga lista de lenguajes de programaciòn.

Answer (score 31):

El operador **|** corresponde mas exactamente al operador **OR** a nivel de operaciones con bits *(bitwise operators).*

En los lenguajes de programación, podemos trabajar con numero binarios (0, 1) y entre ellos se pueden hacer operaciones como en el sistema decimal (0...9). Suma, Resta, Multiplicación, División.

**¿Pero entonces, que significa este operador?**

Vamos por partes.

#### Analicemos este ejemplo

```
public class Ejemplo {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        int A = 8;
        int B = 4;

        int C = A | B;

        System.out.println("Resultado: " + C);
    }

}
```

#### Primero

Veamos nuestros dos números

- 8
- 4

Bien, ahora debemos convertirlos a binarios.

- 8   (1000)
- 4   (0100)

De acuerdo, ya están en binario, ahora a que corresponde la operación "|" (OR) a nivel de bit.

> Si por lo menos uno de los dos bits comparados es 1, establece el resultado en 1. De lo contrario da como resultado 0.

**¿Que quiere decir esto?**

Si tomamos cada uno de los bits (0 ó 1) del resultado del números binarios y lo operamos con el que se encuentra debajo, **si al menos uno de los dos bits es uno** entonces sera un uno.

```
(1000)
(0100)
-----------------
(1100)
```

**¿Ves?**

Al realizar esta operación nos ha dado un nuevo numero binario `1100`, pero **¿Que numero es este en binario?**

```
(1100) -> 8 + 4 + 0 + 0 = 12
```

Y si realizamos la ejecución del programa:

> run:
>
> Resultado: 12

### Actualización

Ahora, miremos tu ejemplo:

- 20      (10100)
- 30      (11110)
- 1000    (1111101000)

Realicemos la operación sobre estos números:

```
(0000010100)
(0000011110)
(1111101000)
------------
 1111111110
```

Nos da como resultado este numero `1111111110`, por lo cual concluimos que equivale a:

```
(1111111110) -> 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 +2 = 1022
```

Espero que te quede un poco mas claro, al respecto del por que de esos resultados.

### Actualización II

Para dejar un poco mas claro esta respuesta, y con el fin de satisfacer dudas a futuros usuarios, te explico un poco mas al respecto.

*De donde nos basamos para entender el valor del **OR**?*

Debemos recurrir a las tablas de verdad:

*Hagamos de cuenta que 1 es Verdadero y 0 es Falso*

```
P  Q   P ^ Q   P v Q
1  1     1       1
1  0     0       1
0  1     0       1
0  0     0       0
```

> **Recuerda que en las tablas de verdad:**
>
> ^ Significa Y
>
> v Significa O

Entonces de este punto podriamos hablar de otro de los operadores que podriamos encontrar en Java a nivel de operaciones de bits, el **AND** o **&**.

La explicacion respecto a este operador, es similar a la del operador **OR** salvo que este, funcionara asi:

> Si cada uno de los dos bits comparados equivalen a 1, establece el resultado en 1. De lo contrario da como resultado 0.

Por lo tanto, si revisasemos el ejemplo de 8 y 4:

```
8 & 4
```

Al realizar esta operacion **&**:

```
(1000)
(0100)
-----------------
(0000)
```

Nos daria `0000`, lo que en este caso equivale a:

```
(0000) -> 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0
```

*Véase en: [Operadores de bits](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Operadores_de_bits) allí podrás ver otros operadores de bits (&, |, <<, >>).*

Answer (score 11):

El operador **|** significa **or** a nivel de bits.

> Una operación OR de bit a bit, o bitwise, toma dos o más números enteros y
>   realiza la operación OR inclusivo en cada par correspondiente de bits.

Para explicar usamos el primer caso que es:

```
int c = 20|30|1000;
```

Convertimos los valores a binario
‭

```
20=00010100‬
‭30=00011110‬
‭1000=001111101000‬
```

Ahora hacemos un **or** entre cada uno de los **bits**

```
    000000010100‬
    0‭00000011110‬
‭    001111101000‬
    _____________
‭    000001111001‬
```

**000001111001** convertido a decimal nos da 121, que es lo que imprimes.

‬

Aquí un ejemplo más breve de **or** a nivel de bits:

```
   0101
OR 0011
   ____
   0111
```

Hay que recordar lo que es la tabla de verdad para el or:

```
A   B   A OR B
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   1
```

Answer (score 10):

Este operador se llama [bitwise inclusive OR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), en castellano sería: **operador OR inclusivo bit a bit**

### ¿Qué hace?

El operador OR inclusivo bit a bit ( | ) compara cada bit del primer operando con el bit correspondiente del segundo operando, produciendo un valor puro que es el `OR` de sus operandos. Si uno de los dos bits es 1, el bit del resultado correspondiente se establece en 1. De lo contrario, el bit del resultado correspondiente se establece en 0.

Lo podemos ver claramente en esta imagen. Vemos en los valores de la línea central cómo se va produciendo el resultado final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si queremos verlo en código Java, podemos ver los resultados de este pequeño programa:

#### `Código:` [`ver demo`](http://rextester.com/SWSZT56351)

```
class Rextester
{  
    private static int i;
    private static int j;
    private static int k;

    public  static void main(String args[])
    {
         i=7;
         j=5;
         k=i|j;

         printResult(i,j,k);
         System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");       

         i=141;
         j=154;
         k=i|j;

         printResult(i,j,k);


         System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");       

         i=788;
         j=657;
         k=i|j;

         printResult(i,j,k);        

         System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");       

         i=10000;
         j=12000;
         k=i|j;

         printResult(i,j,k);        

    }

        private static  void printResult(int i, int j, int k)
        {
                System.out.println("Variable i\tDecimal:\t"+i + "\tBinario:\t" + Integer.toBinaryString(i));
                System.out.println("Variable j\tDecimal:\t"+j + "\tBinario:\t" + Integer.toBinaryString(j));
                System.out.println("i | j = k \tDecimal:\t"+k + "\tBinario:\t" + Integer.toBinaryString(k));
        }

}
```

#### `Resultado`

Se han convertido los números en binario usando [`Integer.toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) para poder analizar cómo se construye el resultado final.

> ```
> Variable i    Decimal:    7       Binario:    111
> Variable j    Decimal:    5       Binario:    101
> i | j = k     Decimal:    7       Binario:    111
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> Variable i    Decimal:    141     Binario:    10001101
> Variable j    Decimal:    154     Binario:    10011010
> i | j = k     Decimal:    159     Binario:    10011111
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> Variable i    Decimal:    788     Binario:    1100010100
> Variable j    Decimal:    657     Binario:    1010010001
> i | j = k     Decimal:    917     Binario:    1110010101
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> Variable i    Decimal:    10000   Binario:    10011100010000
> Variable j    Decimal:    12000   Binario:    10111011100000
> i | j = k     Decimal:    12272   Binario:    10111111110000
> ```

### ¿Cómo funciona?

El operador `|` se evalúa de izquierda a derecha. Y nunca produce una excepción.

Se puede usar por ejemplo con código como este en Java::

```
setFont("Helvetica", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 18);
```

Los operandos deben ser de tipo entero o de tipo booleano, de lo contrario habrá error de compilación.

Si ambos operandos son de tipos enteros, el operador realiza una operación OR inclusiva en el bit. El operador puede realizar conversiones de tipo en los operandos:

- Si cualquiera de los operandos es de tipo `long`, el otro operando se convierte en `long`  y la operación produce un valor `long`.
- De lo contrario, ambos operandos se convierten en `int` y la operación produce un valor `int`.

Si ambos operandos son de tipo booleano, el operador realiza una operación lógica OR inclusiva. La operación lógica inclusiva OR produce un valor puro de tipo booleano. Si uno o ambos operandos son verdaderos, la operación produce verdadero (`true`); de lo contrario la operación produce falso (`false`).

Este operador difiere del operador OR condicional (`||`) porque siempre evalúa ambos de sus operandos, incluso si su operando izquierdo se evalúa como verdadero.

---

### Pero... esto suena a medio chino ¿no? ¿Para qué sirve tanto rollo?

Lo cierto es que para la mayoría de aplicaciones que desarrollamos en Java esto no tendría gran utilidad, pero cuando nos vamos a la programación de *bajo nivel*... Bajo nivel no se refiere a la calidad del programador, sino a que te sumerges más en el código, o sea, que te enfrentas cara a cara con la máquina ... y ahí te quiero ver :)

En programación de *bajo nivel* esto tiene una utilidad enorme, ya que podemos por ejemplo **pasar múltiples opciones a una función usando un sólo número entero**, lo cual repercute en un ahorro de memoria considerable.

Esto no es tan fácil de explicar, pero vamos a tomar un ejemplo que nos suene.

Pensemos en un `Dialog Box` en el cual nos aparecen varias opciones: `SÍ, NO, OK, CANCEL`.

Eso nos suena, ¿verdad?

Supongamos que tenemos que construir una clase para manejar nuestro cuadro de diálogo.

Un programador de *alto nivel*, es decir, uno que en realidad nunca se enfrenta cara a cara con la máquina, escribiría la clase de este modo:

```
public class PopupWindow extends Sprite
{
    // Variables, Constructor, etc...


    public static void showPopup(yesButton:Boolean, noButton:Boolean, okayButton:Boolean, cancelButton:Boolean)
    {
        if(yesButton)
        {
            // add YES button
        }

        if(noButton)
        {
            // add NO Button
        }
        // and so on for the rest of the buttons
    }
}
```

Este código tiene algunos *problemas*:

- Le estamos pasando cuatro parámetros al método
- Tienes que buscar el orden de los argumentos cada vez que llamas a la función.
- Si sólo deseas mostrar el botón Cancelar, debes configurar todos los demás booleanos como falsos.

¿Y que tal si aplicamos operadores bit a bit?

El código quedaría más o menos así:

```
public class PopupWindow extends Sprite
{
    public static const YES:int = 1;
    public static const NO:int = 2;
    public static const OKAY:int = 4;
    public static const CANCEL:int = 8;

    public static void showPopup(buttons:int)
    {
        if(buttons & YES)
        {
            // add YES button
        }

        if(buttons & NO)
        {
            // add NO button
        }   
    }
}
```

¿Cómo podría un programador llamar a la función para que se muestren el botón Sí, el botón No y el botón Cancelar?

De este modo:

```
PopupWindow.show(PopupWindow.YES | PopupWindow.NO | PopupWindow.CANCEL);
```

¿Que esta pasando? Es importante notar que nuestras constantes en el segundo ejemplo son todas potencias de dos. Por lo tanto, si nos fijamos en sus formas binarias, notaremos que todos tienen un dígito igual a 1, y el resto igual a 0. De hecho, cada uno tiene un dígito diferente igual a 1. Esto significa que no importa cómo los combinemos, cuando usemos el operador `|`.

Para nuestro ejemplo actual tenemos:

**`PopupWindow.YES | PopupWindow.NO | PopupWindow.CANCEL`**

que es equivalente:

**`1 | 2 | 8`**

que reescrito en binario es:
**`00000001 | 00000010 | 00001000`**

que nos da un resultado de:

**`00001011`**

Ahora, si en nuestro método `showPopup()`, usamos el operador `&` para comprobar qué opciones fueron pasadas. Por ejemplo, cuando comprobamos los botones `& YES`, todos los bits en `YES` son iguales a `0` excepto el más a la derecha. Por lo tanto, estamos esencialmente comprobando si el bit más a la derecha en los botones es un 1 o no. Si lo es, los botones  `YES` no serán iguales a 0 y cualquier cosa en la sentencia `if` será ejecutada. Por el contrario, si el bit más a la derecha en los botones es 0, los botones `& YES` serán iguales a 0 y la sentencia `if` no se ejecutará.

Geeenial, ¿no?

Pero eso no es nada, comparado a operaciones más complicadas que pueden hacerse usando estos operadores y combinándolos.

Si queremos empezar a ser programadores de *bajo nivel*, podemos probar con algo parecido al ejemplo de más arriba... o con algo de mucho más bajo nivel, más complicado.

Cabe decir, que los números asignados son escogidos de forma inteligente por el programador, para que ocurra lo mencionado más arriba, de forma que no haya nunca coincidencia de resultados y el código se nos haga un lío, o la máquina explote o se funda. :)

---

### Un ejemplo típico

Si nosotros analizamos la [`Clase SWT`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2FSWT.html) de Eclipse, podremos ver fácilmente que utiliza operaciones binarias para casi todo.

Por ejemplo, para un simple botón [`CANCEL`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2FSWT.html), dice:

> ```
> public static final int CANCEL
>
> The MessageBox style constant for a CANCEL button; 
> valid combinations are OK|CANCEL, YES|NO|CANCEL, RETRY|CANCEL 
> (value is 1<<8).
> ```

---

Referencias:

- [Especificaciones del Lenguaje Java (15.22.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1)
- [Documentación Java: Operadore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)s
- [Java Language References: Bitwise/Logical Operators](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/langref/ch04_10.htm)
- [Understanding Bitwise Operators](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301)

Comment: Excelente respuesta, toda una documentación. Solo para añadir, es común utilizar enteros como una minificación de los recursos a ocupar para mantener información booleana, por ejemplo mantener 3 banderas booleanas se necesitan como mínimo 12 bytes, mientras que con un entero podemos mantener 32 banderas solapadas utilizando solamente 4 bytes! , esto ahorra suficiente memoria y es relativamente facil de implementar, en ajedrez se utiliza esta tecnica para implementar bitboards https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Bitboards

Comment: Esta es una muy buena respuesta, muy bien explicada, incluso da ejemplos que ni yo habia entendido

Answer (score 2):

Este operador significa (o), en este contexto se utiliza para saber si la variable tiene el valor citado en diferentes sistemas numericos, en este caso Sistema decimal y Sistema binario

Answer (score 2):

El operador | (or binario) es un operador que trabaja a nivel de bits, compara bit a bit los valores en cuestion, suponiendo que tenemos int a = 1 | 2; primero convierte 1 y 2 a binario, luego compara cada bit de ambos de la siguiente manera:

```
0 | 0 = 0
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

luego el resultado que esta en binario lo vuelve a convertir a decimal.

En tu ejemplo seria de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los operadores de bit son muy utilizados cuando se quiere optimizar el tamaño de los recursos, por ejemplo si necesitas simular una matriz que almacenara solamente dos valores lo adecuado seria usar un objeto java tipo byte pero un byte nos permite almacenar valores hasta 255, lo cual es mucho desperdicio, peor aun si vas a usar millones de ellos.