# Fórmula para definir un Boolean

Tags: java

Creando un listado en el que el parámetro solved (boolean) será true o false (uno sí y otro no).

Yo hubiera formulado un `if`, pero en mi libro de referencia me encuentro esta fórmula.

```
crime.setSolved(i % 2 == 0)
```

Este tipo de condicional no lo había visto antes y me gustaría saber cómo se llama para poder encontrar más ejemplos de su uso.

Dejo el código entero para que se entienda el contexto:

```
private CrimeLab(Context context){
        mCrimes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            Crime crime = new Crime();
            crime.setTitle("Crime #" + i);
            crime.setSolved(i % 2 == 0);
            mCrimes.add(crime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seguramente tu duda está en el `%` que es el operador que consigue el resto de la división. Se llama "operador módulo". La condicion se traduciria por "si el resto de dividir `i` entre 2 es igual a 0" (lo que indica que es par). El codigo parece ser algo no muy funcional ya que pondria el estado de Resuelto a todos los crimenes con ID par.. Un saludo

Comment: Como dice @lois6b, eso es una especie de pseudo binario que suele usarse en Java para alternar, ya que los únicos valores posibles ante esa operación son `0` ó `1`.  Puedes verificar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34247625/5587982) o bien [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242987/5587982), de una pregunta similar a la tuya, la cual no fue tan bien acogida por la versión inglesa de SO, a pesar de que la respuesta aceptada es interesante. Si pruebas esto: `int i=0;
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i % 2 == 0);
        }` verás...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es una especie de pseudo binario que suele usarse en Java para alternar (entre `true` y `false` generalmente, ya que los únicos valores posibles ante esa operación son `0` ó `1`.

Puedes verificar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34247625/5587982) o bien [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242987/5587982), de una pregunta similar a la tuya, la cual no fue tan bien acogida por la versión inglesa de SO, a pesar de que la respuesta aceptada es interesante.

Hagamos una prueba:

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i % 2 == 0);
    }
```

**Resultado:**

```
false
true
false
true
false
true
false
true
false
true
```

Hagamos una prueba con el valor que se produce:

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i % 2);
    }
```

**Resultado:**

```
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
```

---

### En conclusión

Lo que hace `i % 2 == 0` es pasar un valor booleano a tu método, al ser llamado dentro de un bucle, lo que se pretende es establecer valores alternos en el orden `false` ... `true`... ¿El motivo?  Eso ya dependerá del contexto de tu programa.

Lo cierto es que en Java la operación `i % 2 == 0` puede usarse como una estrategia de programación interesante (`true`... `false`,  `apagado` ... `encendido`, `0`... `1`), [algo parecido a lo ocurre con los operadores binarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59030/29967).

Answer (score 3):

Puedes escribir esa línea de un modo más claro así:

```
int remainder = i % 2 //módulo 2 de i, es decir, 1 si i es impar o 0 en otro caso.
boolean solved = result == 0; //es par i?
crime.setSolved(solved);
```

En términos generales, cuando quieres guardar un boolean es más rápido evitar los `if`:

```
if (cond) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

es lo mismo que:

```
return cond;
```

Answer (score 1):

En la expresión `i % 2 == 0` el operador módulo `%` se usa para calcular el residuo de la división entera entre 2. Básicamente indica cuando el residuo de un división da un número exacto, por ejemplo `4 / 2` da `2` y sobran `0`. Este operador es muy útil cuando quieres expresiones de tipo `cada 2, cada 3, cada 10, etc.`. Aquí está un ejemplo para `cada 5`:

```
for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++){
  System.out.println(i % 5 == 0);
}
```

Este código imprimiría `true` al 5, 10, 15, 20, y así hasta llegar al 100.

Espero que esto te ayude con más ejemplos de cómo usarlo.